# HAProxy load balancing check

Tags: load-balancing, ldap, haproxy, pfsense

I have two LDAP servers that replicate together on my LAN. I have a Pfsense CE that performs a load balancing on my two servers for the requests from the WAN. Is it possible to check the number of requests that were sent to each of my servers ? I would like to check if my load balancing is working properly. Is it possible to use the statistics features of the tool ? Thank you.

Comment: See the HAProxy [stats socket](https://docs.haproxy.org/2.7/configuration.html#3.1-stats%20socket) and [UNIX socket commands](https://docs.haproxy.org/2.7/management.html#9.3). Feel free to write a detailed answer to your own question for future reference :)